# why my android app always show UI from xml present in layout folder

Tags: android, android-layout, multiscreen

I am facing issue with my layout, layout-large and layout x-large folders.

When I run my application on moto g or other mobiles with large or xlarge display UI still shows from layout folder.

Why its not reading layout-large files.

Comment: Try renaming the folder to `layout-sw600dp`

Comment: layout-w720-h1280 and Remove layout folder form your project

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008199/what-layout-is-suitable-for-720x1280-android-devices

Comment: @Aniruddha have already tried your solution. Issue present in that too.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder in **res** with the name as `layout-sw600dp` for portrait mode and `layout-sw600dp-land` for landscape mode.

Make sure the layout xml file name should be same in all layout files. If the file name is not same then the it will pick up the file from default layout folder automatically.

Here is more on this

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html